# Unexpected type number expected a URI string error in Expo Web

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a React Native app on Expo Web. I'm trying to load custom fonts as instructed from Expo Documentation on loading custom fonts. But I get the error `Unexpected type number expected a URI string or Asset from expo-asset`. I've searched online but there's no solution mentioning this problem.

```
state = { fontLoaded: false };
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Merriweather: require('./assets/fonts/Merriweather.ttf')
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  } catch (e) {console.log(e); }
};
```

Detailed in https://snack.expo.io/@uahnbu/romee

Comment: I have the same issue, it just started without any change in the fonts loading logics, did you solved it ?

Comment: No. The problem hasn't been solved. Expo Web is just your experimental environment before moving to a more professional option. Read React Native environment setup to built your own env. See [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Comment: Wow good to know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing `require` with `import` or by creating a new object that pick the path in `fonts[key].default`